# How do I set selection on TextField in Air 2.7 for iOS?

Tags: ios, flash, actionscript-3, air

I am trying to use `setSelection` on a `TextField` in an air 2.7 for ios app. But the selection is not set and the keyboard does not appear. I understand that the 2.7 version encourages using the `requestSoftKeyboard` but this method is not supported on ios devices.

It works fine in the desktop version.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to forcibly set the `stage.focus` to your `TextField`.

```
var myTF:TextField = new TextField();
myTF.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;

addChild(myTF);
stage.focus = myTF;
```

Read more in the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#focus) (which is where I stole this snippet)

Comment: thx but i'm doing that allready - and it does not seem to work as intended.

Comment: @DennisFlood did you ever figure this one out?